# Pygame on Mac Mojave

Tags: python, pygame

I've setup a development environment using Python `3.7.2`, Pyenv, and Pygame `1.9.4`. When executing the python file, `python3 ./main.py` I get a blank Pygame screen. See picture below:

[image]

> Many other posts suggest that Pygame does not yet work with the macOS Mojave. I'm not sure I believe that.

The code in my project looks like the following:

```
import pygame

WHITE = (255, 255, 255)
RED = (255, 0, 0)

pygame.init()

size = (700, 500)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)

pygame.display.set_caption('My Game')

done = False

clock = pygame.time.Clock()

while not done:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            done = True

        screen.fill(WHITE)

        pygame.draw.rect(screen, RED, [20, 20, 250, 100], 2)

        pygame.display.flip()

        clock.tick(60)
pygame.quit()
```

> To verify that it was not my code failing, I ran: `python3 -m pygame.examples.aliens` which opens a blank window and plays music.

Has anyone had luck getting this to work on their computer

Comment: Did you install via homebrew? I heard that some people were having issues when installed this way, and they had to do a fresh install of the latest python and install pygame with pip.

Comment: I installed and created a virtual environment using Pyenv then used pip to install Pygame.

Comment: any luck ???! mojave man

Comment: @Marin unfortunately I’ve had no luck. My suspicion is that it isn’t yet compatible with Mojave. I’ve been monitoring this issue: https://github.com/pygame/pygame/issues/555

Comment: @ChaseHardin, I've tried different things and no luck myself was just wondering if there is a way ... I hope you find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on my macbook Pro (2015) on latest OS (mojave). 
It works fine when I followed the instruction on this github issue:

https://github.com/pygame/pygame/issues/555 (Thanks @ChaseHardin)

It seems to be a problem with SDL, dark mode (mojave), brew and python.
You have to run:

```
brew uninstall --force python3
```

Install python by hand on https://www.python.org/downloads/release/python-372/ 
    -> Choose python x 64 macos installer.

```
pip3 install pygame
```

Your screen will be red. (mine was green, i never be so happy to see ugly green in my life).